# Calculate Gross Profit W/O Sell

Tags: c#, .net, accounting

Trying to make myself a small project for work that will calculate gross profit without needing a sell price. Can anyone explain why this is getting marked down? we all needed help at one point..

I currently have 4 text boxes, Cost, Sell, Gross Profit Margin, Markup

How i normally do it it excel is `=Cost/(1-Gp Markup)` and this would return $14.99 sell @ $12.74 cost for example @ 15%

My code is below any help would be appreciated :)

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   double cost = Convert.ToDouble(costTextBox.Text);
   double grossmargin = Convert.ToDouble(grossmarginTextBox.Text);
   double grossSellFinal = cost + (cost * grossmargin)/100;
   // This returns $14.65 which is a mark up not gross profit
   sellTextBox.Text = grossSellFinal.ToString();
}
```

I have also tried this

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   double cost = Convert.ToDouble(costTextBox.Text);
   double grossmargin = Convert.ToDouble(grossmarginTextBox.Text);
   double grossSellFinal = cost / (1 - grossmargin);
   //This returns a sell of -0.91
   sellTextBox.Text = grossSellFinal.ToString();
}
```

https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/financial/margin-calculator.php?cost=12.74&revenue=14.99&action=solve

Comment: What result do you receive? Or which errors?

Comment: Hi Shultc, no errors simply getting the wrong answer. the correct answer should be **Sell $14.99** i can only manage to get 14.65 or 0.91 which are both incorect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your formula that Sell should be equal to Cost / (1 - Gross Profit Margin), where Gross Profit Margin is a decimal between 0 and 1):

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   decimal cost = Convert.ToDecimal(costTextBox.Text);
   decimal grossmargin = Convert.ToDecimal(grossmarginTextBox.Text);
   decimal grossSellFinal = cost / (1 - grossmargin);
   sellTextBox.Text = grossSellFinal.ToString();
}
```

If you are entering `grossmargin` as a value between 0 and 100, you should divide that value by 100:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   decimal cost = Convert.ToDecimal(costTextBox.Text);
   decimal grossmargin = Convert.ToDecimal(grossmarginTextBox.Text);
   decimal grossSellFinal = cost / (1 - grossmargin/100);
   sellTextBox.Text = grossSellFinal.ToString();
}
```

Likewise, it'd also be advisable to throw some kind of error/warning if the enter an illegal value (e.g. `grossmargin` = 1):

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   decimal cost = Convert.ToDecimal(costTextBox.Text);
   decimal grossmargin = Convert.ToDecimal(grossmarginTextBox.Text);
   if (grossmargin > 100)
   {
       sellTextBox.Text = "Error message here";
   }
   else 
   {
       decimal grossSellFinal = cost / (1 - grossmargin/100);
       sellTextBox.Text = grossSellFinal.ToString();
   }
}
```

I'm not sure the proper accounting way to handle the divide by zero case, so the above is just an example. I'll leave the actual implementation to you.

Comment: Better change "double" to decimal. Or there can be really nasty artifacts after all this math

Comment: @Shultc Agreed. Prevent the follow-up "where are these weird floating point errors coming from?" question.

Answer (score 0):

Your two calculations are doing very different things:

One is cost * 115%
One is cost / 85%

Your second example fails because you have a margin of 1500% (you don't divide by 100)

If you use "0.15" as a gross margin in your second example, you should get a sell of "14.9882352941176"

Comment: Also, for money it is better to use "decimal" type.